# Define global variables

Tags: global-variables, libreoffice-calc, libreoffice-basic

I'm trying to test some algorithms in LibreOffice Calc and I would like to have some global variables visible in all cell/sheets. I searched the Internet and all the posts I have seen are so cryptic and verbose!

What are some simple instructions of how can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using user-defined functions should be the most flexible solution to define constants. In the following, I assume the current Calc spreadsheet file is named `test1.ods`. Replace it with the real file name in the following steps:

1. In Calc, open menu *Tools* → *Macros* → *Organize Macros* → *LibreOffice Basic*:

   [image]
2. At the left, select the current document `test1.ods`, and click <kbd>New...</kbd>:

   [image]
3. Click <kbd>OK</kbd> (Module1 is OK).

   [image]

   Now, the Basic IDE should appear:

   [image]
4. Below `End Sub`, enter the following BASIC code:

   ```Basic
    Function Var1()
        Var1 = "foo"
    End Function

    Function Var2()
        Var2 = 42
    End Function
   ```

   The IDE should look as follows:

   ```
   [![Enter image description here][5]][5]
   ```
5. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> to save.

This way, you've defined two global constants (to be precise: two custom functions that return a constant value). Now, we will use them in your spreadsheet. Switch to the LibreOffice Calc's main window with file `test1.ods`, select an empty cell, and enter the following formula:

```
=Var1()
```

LibreOffice will display the return value of your custom Var1() formula, a simple string. If your constant is a number, you can use it for calculations. Select another empty cell, and enter:

```
=Var2() * 2
```

LibreOffice will display the result `84`.

Comment: I like the idea, although there is an easier way that avoids macros.

Comment: @JimK I agree - i didn't knew that you can explicitly set the scope of named ranges. +1 for your solution, i would recommend it as accepted answer.

Answer (score 15):

Go to *Sheet* → *Named Ranges and Expressions* → *Define*. Set name to "MyVar1" and expression to 5.  Or for strings, use quotes as in `"foo"`.  Then press <kbd>Add</kbd>.

[image: Define Name]

Now enter `=MyVar1 * 2` in a cell.

[image: Cell formula]

Comment: This is actually way easier than the other answer, Thanks!

Comment: To add to Jim's answer, you can quickly define a cell as a variable by selecting it and entering the desired variable name into the 'Name Box' (e.g. where it says 'A1' in Jim's second screenshot)

Answer (score 5):

One strategy is to save the global variables you need on a sheet:

[image: Variable cell default name]

Select the cell you want to reference in a calculation and type a variable name into the 'Name Box' in the top left where it normally says the Cell Column Row.

[image: Set name for cell/range of cells]

Elsewhere in your project you can reference the variable name from the previous step:

[image: Using a variable name in a calculation]