# How to solve nonlinear equations in LibreOffice Calc?

Tags: numerical-methods, solver, nonlinear-optimization, libreoffice-calc, nonlinear-equation

I want to solve an equation that is an integration of [Miner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatigue_(material)#Miner%27s_rule) and [Wöhler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/August_W%C3%B6hler) formulas:

```latex
\frac{n_1}{N_1} + \frac{n_2}{N_2} = 1
```

where:

- `n1`s are stored in column A (assume numbers in 10^6-10^8 range)
- `n2`s are stored in column B (assume numbers in 10^5-10^6 range)
- `Ni`s including `N1`s and `N2`s are defined as:

```latex
log_{10} \left( N_i \right) = 7 \left( 1 - \frac{\sigma_{f_i} - \sigma_e}{\sigma_u - \sigma_e} \right)
```

- <sub>u</sub> `sigma_u` is a global variable as instructed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47440208/4999991). (assume 1300)
- and <sub>f<sub>i</sub></sub>s

  - <sub>f<sub>1</sub></sub>s stored in column C (assume random numbers between 200-300 range)
  - <sub>f<sub>2</sub></sub>s stored in column D (assume random numbers between 200-300 range)

I tried looking into the "Solver for Nonlinear Programming" extension for Calc [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/libreoffice/comments/127gfvm/what_is_the_solver_for_nonlinear_programming/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3), but I can't find proper documentation for that.

I can solve the nonlinear equation in Maxima/WxMaxima using the

```
find_root(n1 / N1 + n2 / N2 - 1, sigma_e, 200, 300);
```

function, but I don't know how to do it in LibreOffice Calc so I can map it to those columns.